# SignalR Where/How server calls hub

Tags: c#, vb.net

Can anyone tell me how/where in what place signalr server calls hub? Below find my code. How the hell RunServ knows my hub main called "Main" where is the call to it from server. All works well. I've checked when changed name of hub to "Whatever" then i get error means server has somwhere reference to this hub. Where it is?

```
Module RunServ

    Private SignalR As IDisposable
    Private Const Address As String = "http://+:4848/"

    Sub Main()
        Task.Run(Sub() StartServer()).Wait()
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Private Sub StartServer()
        Try
            SignalR = WebApp.Start(Of Startup)(Address)
            Console.WriteLine("Server is running")

        Catch generatedExceptionName As TargetInvocationException
            Console.WriteLine("Server error")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub StopServer()
        SignalR.Dispose()
    End Sub

End Module


Public Class Startup

        'This simply enables the hub to communicate cross-domain, and correctly maps all the SignalR hubs in the application for us.
        Public Sub Configuration(app As IAppBuilder)

            Dim hubConfiguration = New HubConfiguration()
            hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = True
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll)
            app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration)

        End Sub
    End Class


   <HubName("Main")>
    Public Class HubMain
        Inherits Hub '(Of IHubMain)

        Public Overrides Function OnConnected() As Task
            Clients.All.userJoined("anonymous")
            Console.WriteLine("Connected connection id: " + Context.ConnectionId)
            Return MyBase.OnConnected()
        End Function

        Public Overrides Function OnReconnected() As Task
            Console.WriteLine("Reconnected connection id: " + Context.ConnectionId)
            Return MyBase.OnReconnected()
        End Function
...
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have server application, that listens to requests of clients. On server side, you have classes called Hubs, which represents the functionality that should be called from clients. Then you have client, that creates instance of IHubProxy, and that calls methods specified by string (their name) that should exist on server side. In comparison to WCF, it is extremely simple and easy to use.